# NVRAM: Error clearing firmware variables: (iokit/common) not permitted

Tags: terminal, catalina, nvram

I cannot reset my NVRAM at startup (holding down <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> does nothing), but I want to reset the NVRAM so I am trying to reset it with Terminal.

```
$ sudo nvram -c
nvram: Error clearing firmware variables: (iokit/common) not permitted
```

How do I reset the NVRAM?

Comment: Is this a new Mac with a T2 chip?

Comment: no, this mac is a few years old

Comment: @porker7 Try the startup key combination to reset the NVRAM or try doing sudo nvram -c from Single User mode.

Comment: @Todd no startup key combinations work which is why I want to do this nvram reset

Comment: @porker7 Have you tried Single User or Recovery?

Comment: @Todd if I can't use startup keys then how can I enter those modes?

Comment: There is a certain Variable that you can add to the NVRAM which will start in macOS Recovery upon the next restart. This is one time though.

Comment: @Todd "There is a certain Variable that you can add to the NVRAM which will start in macOS Recovery upon the next restart." What is/are the variables?

Answer (score 7):

This should do the trick:

```
$ sudo nvram ResetNVRam=1 && sudo reboot
```

It basically sets the `ResetNVRam` variable and reboots. The NVRAM is reset, similar to using the keyboard keys, whenever a Mac is rebooted with this NVRAM variable set.

Comment: This worked great on macOS Big Sur 11.7.3 (20G1116).

Answer (score 6):

Despite the error message, the NVRAM has been cleared. Found this on another forum that proves it out:

```
$ sudo nvram TestVar=HelloWorld
$ sudo nvram -p | grep 'TestVar'
TestVar HelloWorld
$ sudo nvram -c
nvram: Error clearing firmware variables: (iokit/common) not permitted
$ sudo nvram -p | grep 'TestVar'
$
```

Comment: I think you have been fooled my friend.  The above does NOT prove that the NVRAM was cleared, only that 'TestVar' was added to it.  I think the error message, `Error clearing firmware variables: (iokit/common) not permitted` already showed and continues to show that the nvram is not cleared...

Answer (score 2):

I used the above terminal method and terminal spit out this new response:

`'ResetNVRam': (iokit/common) privilege violation.`

What is `iokit/common` even referencing?

I started experiencing this problem after installing an audio interface.
(Apollo Twin X Duo) I remember I had to startup in recovery mode and enable special privileges at one point in the installation. I don't know if this is related. Maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

`nvram ResetNVRam=1 && reboot` fixed my external monitor resolution after update 13.3.1. (sudo might be required)

Comment: I did this with a terminal in the « startup options » so my access was already granted, in this specific case sudo is not required. But if you startup your mac normally and open a terminal you might effectively use sudo. (but I didn’t do this way, so I haven’t tested it but it sound logical). But thanks for your constructive reply :)

Comment: right.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ